# Declaring a variable, IF and SWITCH state. Good Practices

Tags: c++

CIndent and CCSV have the same parent class and that is what i'm passing in printFile, is this good idea using an If or a SWITCH to declare the variables  ?

```
if (fileFormat==1)
    CIndent codecWrite;
else
    CCSV codecWrite;

route.prinFile(filename,codecWrite);
```

Do you have an other method ? why ? how ?

Comment: Typically, when you have a set of things based on which you can use another, corresponding set of classes, you use something like a factory, an `std::unordered_map<enum Type, std::function<BaseClass *()>` - i. e. a mapping from thing types to factory functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```
std::unique_ptr<CodecWrite> codecwrite;
if (fileFormat==1)
    codecWrite.reset( new CIndent() );
else
    codecWrite.reset( new CCSV() );

if(codecWrite)
    route.prinFile(filename,*codecWrite);
```

`switch` should be taken into account, if you have more *file formats* to manage

```
std::unique_ptr<CodecWrite> codecwrite;
switch(fileFormat) {
case 1:
    codecWrite.reset( new CIndent() );
    break;
case 2:
    /** I don't know an appropriate class **/
    codecWrite.reset( new AnotherCodecWrite );
    break;
default:
    codecWrite.reset( new CCSV() );
    break;
}

if(codecWrite)
    route.prinFile(filename,*codecWrite);
```

Comment: @pmr past-finishing touch: `std::unordered_map<enum FileFormat, std::function<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>()>>`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant... can you please explain this syntax for my better understanding. Thanks

Comment: Fixed various trivia errors. Hey, what about some coffee? ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf THX for the trivia. _"Hey, what about some coffee?"_ Of course. I'll go to have another one ;-) ...

Comment: @someone there's no much to explain on the syntax. it's just some nested templates. Instead of the switch (which is usually code smell in C++), you map the type IDs to functions that construct an object of the appropriate type.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the invalid code

```
if (fileFormat==1)
    CIndent codecWrite;
else
    CCSV codecWrite;

route.prinFile(filename,codecWrite);
```

…do just

```
route.prinFile( fileFormat == 1? baseRef( CIndent() ) : baseRef( CCSV() ) );
```

where `baseRef` is e.g.

```
auto baseRef( Base&& o ) -> Base& { return o; }
```

This relies on the guarantee that a temporary object is destroyed at the end of the full-expression, and not before.

By the way, I would suggest renaming `prinFile` to `printFile`.

Ken Thompson was once asked what he'd do differently if he were to design Unix again, and answered: “I'd spell *creat* with an *e*!”.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend either approach in this case. `switch` and long chained `if-else if-else` structures are usually code smell in C++, and this case is no exception. If you want to **map** a set of type IDs to a set of classes, then use the appropriate data structure, which in your case is either an array (if you know that your type IDs will always be consecutive integers), or more generally, a lookup table. The former is realized using `std::array`, the latter with `std::unordered_map` in modern C++.

```
enum FileFormat {
    Indent,
    CSV
};

class FileWriter {
    virtual ~FileWriter() {}
    // etc.
};

class IndentWriter : FileWriter {
    virtual ~IndentWriter() {}
    // etc.
};

class CSVWriter : FileWriter {
    virtual ~CSVWriter() {}
    // etc.
};

std::unordered_map<FileFormat, std::function<std::unique_ptr<FileWriter>()>> formatMap {
    { Indent, []() { return std::unique_ptr<FileWriter>(new IndentWriter); } },
    { CSV, []() { return std::unique_ptr<FileWriter>(new CSVWriter); } }
};

FileType type = // obtain type ID however you want

auto objPtr = formatMap[type]();
```